# schedule module Python error in schedule.clear(tag)

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

Hey guys I'm having some trouble with the schedule module. Let's say I tag certain schedules (where xx, yy, aa and bb change every day according to another function not here below)

```
def update_schedules():
    schedule.every().day.at('xx:yy').do(print, 'lol').tag('work')
    schedule.every().day.at('aa:bb').do(print, 'lol').tag('work_1')
```

and then I have another function to clear the schedules, because I don't want them to add up every single day. But instead change every single day.

```
def clear1():
    schedule.clear('work')
    schedule.clear('work_1')

schedule.every().day.at('00:00').do(clear1)

#schedule.every().day.at('00:05').do(#Function That Changes xx, aa, bb, yy)

schedule.every().day.at('00:10').do(update_schedules)
```

I get an error saying that `schedule.clear(tagname)` takes 0 positional argument, but 1 was given.
The thing is, I wanna clear just the schedules above, tagged work and work_1, but not other lines of schedules that I want to keep running. I just want aa:bb and xx:yy to get cleared every day and updated with other values.

Comment: You have overridden `schedule.clear` with a function that takes no argument at some point in your code. Please update your question with more of your relevant code.

Comment: Updated just now

Comment: What I meant is that there must be other parts of your code that references `schedule.clear`, which you haven't included in your question. Can you try finding it and post it here?